# Mockito/PowerMockito checking a return

Tags: java, methods, mockito, return, powermockito

Basically, I have a class, and the important part looks like this:

```
class A{
double num = 2;

public double getNum(){
return num;
  }

}
```

I want to make sure that it **doesn't** look like this:

```
class A{

public double getNum(){
return 2;
  }

}
```

Is there a way to do this with Mockito or PowerMockito?

I am new to PowerMockito, and only a few months into Mockito, so sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: Why would you want to test that? I believe that tests are concerned more on the  behavior than the internal implementation (your field is *package-private* and has no setter).

Comment: Yeah, I'm using Mockito a little unconventionally. It's for high school robotics and we're teaching new students how to control the robot. I don't want them to set the motor power to 0.2; or whatever, I want it to be a variable from an enum that we've given them. Long story, I just wanted to know if I can test whether or not it's a variable or just a number. Since we're using framework made by WPILib, it's kind of like legacy code as certain things have to be done in a certain way. This is a dumbed down version of my problem. Thank you for the answer though. I thought it was impossible, but...

Comment: "I don't want them to set the motor power to 0.2" is something a test could cover. But you would have to think the other way around. Instead of asserting the return value of a getter, you would have to *verify* the argument of the corresponding setter (e.g. `motor.setPower(...)`). In this case you would be testing behavior: "should not set the motor power to 0.2".

Answer (score 0):

```
class A{
  private double num;
  
  public constructor(double num){
    this.num = num;
  }

  public double getNum(){
    return num;
  } 
}
```

If you need it to be like that you will have to try something like above. But there is no point of verifying that since a test should verify the behaviour. It doesn't matter whether it is taking from `service1` or hard-coded text because in some other test that class should definitely fail.

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't. I understand that Mockito was designed to verify behavior, but I was just hoping I was missing something :/. I'm writing these tests to help fellow high school students learn to code robots during the pandemic since they can't use the robot to test. As it's bad practice to hard code numbers, I wanted a way to test that they used a variable. But the number stays the same, it's just that we have a public enum where we change all the numbers. This is just because I want them to learn good practice before I graduate, and I don't have the time to manually check. Oh well. :/

Comment: I also had the same issue with testing some time ago. I wanted to behave the code in a very strict way that verifies by the test. Now I understand the way of the unit test is not like that. It is to verify that the particular method or function behaves as the way we expect. Since it doesn't matter whether how it getting the value as long as it passes the test. The way we need to achieve this is strong the unit test suite with all possible scenarios.